# Implement addon in a script?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

I use the add-on for Google-Analytics on the GSheets and I want to run it before  running a script (Copy Paste values) that I wrote on my own. Do you know how to implement it?

I tried so far to set a timer for both of them (with some hours apart), but something goes wrong and only the script I wrote runs.

As workaround I created a helpout-workbook and run the GA add-on there. Then via importrange I send the result to the original sheet, rearrange it, and then my script works fine.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

### Postpone script execution:

You can use something simple like setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-66666-7','auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

},3000)
```

Comment: The timers were set for different times, one for 1am and the other for 6am. Nevertheless only the script I wrote runs. The add on does not. Hence I am trying now with a help-workbook and importrange. This workaround seems to work, but does not seem reliable and worth recommendation.

Comment: Ok, I don't undersand reason, why you want to run Google Analytics code on your websites - one code at 1am and second code at 6am. I makes totally no sense.